# terminology for "a number with at least two distinct prime factors"

Tags: terminology, prime-factorization

Is there an established terminology for "a number with at least two distinct prime factors"?

These are the composite numbers 6 (2x3), 10 (2x5), 12 (2x2x3), 14 (2x7), 15 (3x5), ...,
but not 4 (2x2), 8 (2x2x2), 9 (3x3), ...

These numbers are neither primes nor prime powers, but this describes them by what they are *not*; I would prefer a concise description of what they *are*, if there is an established terminology for it.  If not, I'm tempted to foist the phrase "*truely-composite number*" onto an unsuspecting world :-)

Comment: To extrapolate from other terminologies, I'd use the term *proper composite number*.

Comment: A positive integer $n$ with $\omega(n) \geq 2$; cf. [omega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor#Omega_functions).

Answer (score 0):

I would be quite hesitant to introduce a nondescriptive name like 'truly-composite' (note spelling of truly).  How about multi-prime composite if you really need a name.

Another way to think about these numbers is as the composites that are not the size of any finite field.